# Idiomatic equivalent of ты крут

Tags: словоупотребление, сленг

(Да) ты крут!

I see this everywhere. Is it the equivalent of (Am.) English "Oh, you're goo(ooo)d..." when someone does something well or shows what he's capable of (usually to the speaker's surprise, who is also duly impressed)?

[Oh, you're good!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7L7lalP1Lk&feature=kp)

Comment: I believe "cool" is reasonably close

Comment: I know it means "cool" - however in this particular usage, "you're cool" doesn't really correspond to "you're good" in the context I described, which is what I suspect this means.

Comment: Hmmm I believe when a person did something exceptionally well and you just say "Cool!" this is usually understood as praising that person, no?

Comment: I mean also in Russian in such case you might also just say "Круто!" and this would mean more or less the same...

Comment: We wouldn't use cool in that situation - and much less "you're cool." We mostly use cool to accept a proposition or agree to something: Shall we go to the beach after lunch? -Cool. Or: I think we're going home after this. -Cool. I'll see you tomorrow. It's like "no problem.'

Comment: I'm asking specifically about ты крут

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cool) lists as one of the meanings of "cool" this -   
colloquial: of a person, knowing what to do and how to behave in any situation;  

I believe this is more or less equivalent...

Comment: If you wrote an extremely impressive English text and I was shocked and impressed by your knowledge of the language, I would never say "you're cool!" - however I would say: "your good!"

Comment: Furthermore, I've been using colloquial English for 50 years - wikipedia can't teach me anything.

Comment: Still wiktionary is less subjective source of information than your personal, albeit impressive experience

Comment: Are you quite finished?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In colloquial American English it would be "you're a badass". Another option is "mean", but it's used to characterize a skill or action, e.g. "that's some mean juggling"

Comment: Ok, so then it is "you're good" - that's what we say in that situation - "badass" is just a more vulgar variant of the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: Крут is not necessarily vulgar, but it's a slang word